# Calculating money value's goes wrong

Tags: php, floating-point, int, currency

I'm trying to add up some numbers (money), but for some reason the output is not what I expected.

The values are:

- 2500.30
- 13.50
- 25
- 5.40
- 120

What I expect is `2664.20`, but the output I get is `163.9`.
Here is my code:

```
// Get the price of the product
$rent = $product->get_price_html();
// Remove the dot and change the comma into a new dot
$rent_float = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $rent));

// Get the custom fields, example: 10.50 (the price)
$gwl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'g/w/l_prijs', true);
$tti = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 't/t/i_prijs', true);
$heffing = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'heffingen_prijs', true);
$verzekering = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'verzekering_prijs', true);

// Change the dots into comma's to make it more readable
$gwl_comma = str_replace('.', ',', $gwl);
$tti_comma = str_replace('.', ',', $tti);
$heffing_comma = str_replace('.', ',', $heffing);
$verzekering_comma = str_replace('.', ',', $verzekering);

// Add up the values where comma's were replaced with dots
$total = $rent_float + $gwl + $tti + $heffing + $verzekering;

// Change the dot from the total into a comma to make it more readable
$total_comma = str_replace('.', ',', $total);
```

I'm removing the dot and changing the comma in the `rent` so I can calculate it more easily with the other values that I'm getting from the custom fields.
 Also, the last 0 is being removed from the final value. I looked this up on google but could only find results related to array's.

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you give me output of $rent

Comment: @AlauddinAnsari It's `2.500,30`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert all the values in some unique format.
eg.

> `####.##`

use `number_format($var, 2)` for this

Later you do not need to remove the dots as php easily adjust with the type of variable without declaring

So when you will have all the values like:

```
2500.30
13.50
25.00
5.40
120.00
```

now sum up all of them and check

Comment: But aren't I already doing this? I already have all those values. The problem is that the output varies from the expected result.

Comment: like I said, "first convert all the values in some unique format". use same number format for all variables

Comment: I am. They're all being changed to use dots, after which I add them up.

Comment: I did put in your code. The values now show exactly as you have it but it still shows me the wrong total.

Comment: I executed this simple snippet which results into your expected result

$a = 2500.30;
$b = 13.50;
$c = 25.00;
$d = 5.40;
$e = 120.00;

echo $a+$b+$c+$d+$e;

What total are you getting from this?

Comment: `2664.2`. I think the problem lies with the rent value. Maybe I need to turn it into a float before calculation.

Comment: I found out that the `$rent` value is not `2500.30` but `€2500.30`. The euro sign is probably causing the problem. I tried removing it with `str_replace` but it doesn't seem to work :S.

Comment: try to use ltrim() or substr()

Comment: I found out I can just get the value from the database through wordpress without it having additional html on it. The calculation works now and I'm adding up the numbers, but the result is `2,664.20` instead of `2.664,20`. Would you know how to switch the comma and dot around?

Comment: str_replace will do the trick. Like $str1 = str_replace(".",",","2,664.20"); $str1 = str_replace(",",".",$str1);

Comment: That wouldn't work. It would replace the dots with a comma, making it `2,664,20`, after which I replace the comma's with a dot, making it `2.664.20`.

Comment: $str1 = str_replace(".","*","2,664.20"); 

$str1 = str_replace(",",".",$str1);

$str1 = str_replace("*",",",$str1);

Comment: Sorry I don't get this code. I replace the dots with nothing, resulting in `2,66420`, after which I replace the comma's with dots, which makes `2.66420`, and then replace nothing with comma's, getting `2.66420`?

Comment: instead of replacing dot with "nothing" use some special character(like I used *) and on last step replace * with ,

Comment: Oh ok as a placeholder? I don't see any `*` so all I saw was an empty space in the code :p.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you struggling so much.

You are doing well on the top. you just need to make all your amount same process as you are doing with rent.

```
$rent = $product->get_price_html();
$rent_float = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $rent));

$gwl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'g/w/l_prijs', true);
$gwl_float = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $gwl));

$tti = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 't/t/i_prijs', true);
$tti_float = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $tti));
```

and so on...

and then finally add all the float value

```
$total = $rent_float + $gwl_float + $tti_float + $heffing_float + $verzekering_float;
```

That's it.

:) enjoy!

Comment: But then it removes the dots from the values (like `$gwl`), which then turns it into `1350` instead of `13.50`.

Comment: Ok then I need output of $gwl

Comment: `13.50`. I'm only changing the dot to a comma later to make it look better on the front. For adding up the values I use the dot version.